# Qlik Sense Desktop to connect to SharePoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, qliksense

What are the steps to connect Qlik Sense Desktop to read excel files on a Sharepoint folder?

Comment: Can you define whether this is office 365, a local instance or a non-local instance of sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

From the QlikSense server application, go to Data Manager (top left, in the compass pull-down).
Open SharePoint in another window.
Drag and drop the Excel file from SP into QS data manager.
Should work the same as drag and drop from the desktop.

Note, the QS server should be on the same domain as the SP server and the QS service account should have privilege to access the file.